# prevent the sql injection through url

Tags: c#, java, sql-injection

Does validating the URL against special characters prevent sql injections? Somehing like this:

```
validateRequest(req.getUri());
```

In which I validate for special characters.

Comment: Never never never try to write your own custom validation for "special" characters to protect from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: SQL injection doesn't happen in a URL.  It happens in a database interaction.  And it has nothing to do with "special characters" and everything to do with treating user input as *data* instead of as *executable code*.

Comment: thanks Kevin :)

David I know that but I mean the case he write a complete sql statement inside the url?\

Answer (score 5):

As long as you are using [parametrized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) against databases you would be saved from SQL Injection. So instead of validating characters in URL, you should send data to the database server through command parameters.

Comment: I am asking if he write the complete sql statement in the url not the usual injection in which the attacker adds something like :
 or 1=1

Comment: @user3204111, how the input from url would go to database server ? It can't go directly, there must be command object/code taking values from URL and then sending it to database. You can't write a SQL query in URL and expect it to go to database automatically, there must be some kind of command object involved.